# Проблема SharedPreferences для отдельных процессов

Tags: java, android

Есть сервис, есть активити, у каждого есть `SharedPreferences`:

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences sPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor sPrefEdit;
final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text"; 

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
sPref = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_TEXT,MODE_PRIVATE);
sPrefEdit = sPref.edit();
...
```

и сервис:

```
public class HealthService extends Service {
SharedPreferences sPref;
SharedPreferences.Editor sPrefEdit;
final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text"; 

...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
sPref = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_TEXT,MODE_PRIVATE);
sPrefEdit = sPref.edit();
```

У них один и тот же файл преференсес, но если сервис записывает что-либо в преференсес, то активити изменения видит только после перезапуска приложения, так же и сервис видит изменения преференсес сделанные активитей только после перезапуска.

Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такова текущая особенность работы `SharedPreferences`.

В *некоторых случаях* можно получить актуальное состояние `SharedPreferences` вызовом метода `getSharedPreferences(...)` с флагом `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`.

Но будьте внимательны, использовать `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` **не рекомендуется**, так как начиная с `API level 23` оно `deprecated`.

> This constant was deprecated in API level 23.
>   MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. **Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as ContentProvider**.

**Правильным решением** проблемы будет написание своего механизма, который будет основываться на `ContentProvider`, или же можно использовать что-то готовое, вроде [этого](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [Dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger) для передачи объекта `SharedPreferences` между частями вашего приложения. Для начала работы с Dagger вам потребуется некоторая подготовка вашего приложения. Об этом подробно написано [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/dagger-2/16-course/dagger2/424-urok-1.html).

Вам понадобится создать класс-модуль:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private final App app;

    public AppModule(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences() {
        return app.getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    App provideApplication() { return app; }
}
```

Чтобы обратиться к объекту `SharedPreferences`, вам необхожимо будет добавить в ваши `Activity` и `HealthService` как поле класса следующую строчку:

```
 @Inject
 SharedPreferences pref;
```

и производить все действия с настройками через это поле.